# Force.com security scanner says no Force.com code accessible in your organization- Any one else having this issue?

Tags: security, appexchange

I have used the force.com security scanner many times before and had no issues with it till now. I got an automated email

> The requested security scan did not return results because there was no Force.com code accessible in your organization.

The user provided is of system admin profile. I am able to login into the environment and see that there is code available.

Is it coz of the load on the security scanner ? I have to wait for another 2 hours before resubmitting again. Hope it doesnt send back the same message again. Is there something else i need to take care of?

Thanks

Comment: I am assume it is an DE org with unmanaged code deployed to it? You've not accidentally given it an org with your managed package only in it have you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the Hosted Service.** I have also experienced increasingly long waits for it to respond, sometimes days. I doubt the message you're getting relates to the delay. Only thing i can think is you perhaps accidentally gave it a DE org with your managed package code in it? You need to ensure the code is in unmanaged form so the service can extract it and scan it properly. 
This [link](http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scannerhelp) provides a good summary of the process, what it can scan, and some guidelines on the length of time to expect...

> In order for the scan to be successfully processed, the following must be true:
>
> Your salesforce.com account must have the "Author Apex" permission enabled.
>   Code must not be contained within a package that has been installed in the org being tested.
>
> Source code that lives inside of packages is not scanned to avoid inadvertently scanning code unrelated to your application.

They are currently displaying this message on their site...

> At this time the Force.com Security Source Code Scanner is experiencing delays. Expect delays as we work through this issue.

Also this message....

> Note that we cannot scan code on NA16

Is your DE org on NA16 by any chance?

**Doing your own Local Scan.** You might be interest to know that they also provide the tool via an [Eclipse plugin](https://www.apexscanner.com/EclipsePlugin/EclipsePluginRequest.aspx), so you can run it locally, installation instructions are [here](https://www.apexscanner.com/EclipsePlugin/UserGuide.aspx). I'm also told there is a batch version of it that you can use in your Continuous Integration build systems (for a fee).

[image]